# Sitecore 9 xconnect error: Sitecore.XConnect.XdbCollectionUnavailableException, Forbidden

Tags: sitecore, sitecore-xdb

The xdb features in our Sitecore 9 installation are not working. I get this error in the Sitecore logs:

> Exception: Sitecore.XConnect.XdbCollectionUnavailableException
>   Message: The HTTP response was not successful: Forbidden

IIS log shows this is a **403.16** exception. I've found various solutions saying this relates to a certificate issue, but none of the solutions have worked for me.

I see two certificates in the "Personal"(My) store with the name indicated in the Sitecore install scripts, on has "_client" appended to it. In the ConnectionStrings.config, all certs referenced show the thumbprint of only the first cert.

Any thoughts on why I get this error?

Comment: Have you checked if the same certificate is also installed under Trusted Root Certification Authorities?

Comment: were you able to figure this out.I am getting same error.I have checked to make sure that non self signed certificates are there in trusted root but can not seem to find one.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if there are any Non Self Signed Certificates in Trusted Root certificates in the Trusted Root Certificates if so delete them or move to Intermediate CA. Please refer to this it may help
https://sitecorecorner.com/2017/10/25/sitecore-9-xconnect-ssl-and-that-403-forbidden/